# Why is QuickSort Single pivot faster than 3-way partition?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to roughly benchmark the performance of QuickSorts (Single Pivot, 3-way and Dual Pivot).

**Questions 1 :** 
I am afraid that I am missing something in the implementation of 3-way partition.  Across several runs against random inputs (of 10 million) numbers, I could see that the single pivot always performs better (although the difference is somewhere around 100 milliseconds for 10 million numbers).

I understand that the whole purpose of 3-way is not 0 (n^2) performance on duplicate keys - which is very evident when I run it against duplicate input.  But is it true that for the sake of handling duplicate data, a small penalty is taken by 3-way? Or my implementation is bad?

***Duplicate Data :***

- Quick Sort Basic : 888 millis
- Quick Sort 3 Way : 522 millis
- Quick Sort Dual Pivot : 482 millis

***Random Data :***

- Quick Sort Basic : 1677 millis
- Quick Sort 3 Way : 1717 millis
- Quick Sort Dual Pivot : 1595 millis

**Question 2 :**

The Dual Pivot implementation (link below) does not handle duplicates well. It takes a 0(n^2) time to execute.  Is there a good way to fast-forward.  I could see that we could check if the pivots are equal and increment pivot1 until it is different than pivot2.  Is this a fair implementation?

```
else if (pivot1==pivot2){
        while (pivot1==pivot2 && lowIndex<highIndex){
            lowIndex++; 
            pivot1=input[lowIndex];
        }
    }
```

**Implementation links :**

Root folder : https://github.com/arunma/dsa/tree/master/src/basics/sorting/quick

QuickSort (Single Pivot) : https://github.com/arunma/dsa/blob/master/src/basics/sorting/quick/QuickSortBasic.java

QuickSort (3-way partition) : 
https://github.com/arunma/dsa/blob/master/src/basics/sorting/quick/QuickSort3Way.java

QuickSort (Dual Pivot) : 
https://github.com/arunma/dsa/blob/master/src/basics/sorting/quick/QuickSortDualPivot.java

TestCase :
https://github.com/arunma/dsa/blob/master/src/basics/sorting/quick/QuickSortTest.java

Comment: Here is OP's work...https://dzone.com/articles/algorithm-week-quicksort-three

Answer (score 0):

First of all get rid of the suffle in the constructors to get right comparison.

Second, the behavior is expected, since in the basic version you are only doing the switch if you find the right candidate in both side, i.e., in QuickSortBasic.java

```
    while (true){

        while (less(input[++i], input[pivotIndex])){
            if (i==highIndex) break;
        }

        while (less (input[pivotIndex], input[--j])){
            if (j==lowIndex) break;
        }

        if (i>=j) break;

        exchange(input, i, j);

    }
```

whereas the 3way version you are doing a switch anyway unless the element is equal to the pivot, i.e., in QuickSort3Way.java

```
    while (i<=gt){


        if (less(input[i],pivotValue)){
            exchange(input, i++, lt++);
        }
        else if (less (pivotValue, input[i])){
            exchange(input, i, gt--);
        }
        else{
            i++;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Answers are intended to be useful for others than just the OP. "check your github pull request" is not very useful to the next person to read this answer, 6 months from no. .)